# How to replace namespace or list of type using Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

This is my code:

```
string _type="System.Collections.Generic.List<PhilpostDB.ViewModel.Person>";
_type = Regex.Replace(_type, @"[.\w]+\.(\w+)", "$1"); // this result=List<Person>
```

I want Result : _type=PhilpostDB.ViewModel.Person

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for:

```
[^<]+\<([^>]+)\>
```

And replace with:

```
$1
```

i.e.:

```
_type = Regex.Replace(_type, @"[^<]+\<([^>]+)\>", "$1");
```

Answer (score 1):

Should work with string methods only:

```
string _type = "System.Collections.Generic.List<PhilpostDB.ViewModel.Person>";
string[] tokens = _type.Split('<');
string result = tokens[0].Split('.').Last();
if (tokens.Length > 1)
{
    string token2 = tokens.Last().Split('.').Last();
    result = string.Format("{0}<{1}", result, token2);
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/6EgmOq)</kbd>

**Edit** thanks tim, but if i want result=PhilpostDB.ViewModel.Person?

```
string genericType = _type.Split('<').Last().TrimEnd('>');
```